# Error on line count step in batch

Tags: batch-file, rows

I used the script as below to check if the file exists and has rows inside, need to run the special process.

```
CLS

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


REM Check the DataFile1.csv exist or not.
If not exist "E:\DataFolder\DataFile1.csv" (
PAUSE >NUL 
    exit /b
) else (
REM Check the DataFile2.csv exist or not.
        If not exist "E:\DataFolder\DataFile2.csv"  (
            exit /b
            )   else    (
REM Check the rows of DataFile1.csv
set file=E:\DataFolder\DataFile1.csv
set /a cnt1=0
for /f %%a in ('type "%file%"^|find "" /v /c') do set /a cnt1=%%a
echo %file% has %cnt1% lines
            IF %cnt1% LSS 2     (
                exit /b
            )   else (
REM Check the rows of DataFile2.csv
set file=E:\DataFolder\DataFile2.csv
set /a cnt2=0
for /f %%a in ('type "%file%"^|find "" /v /c') do set /a cnt2=%%a
echo %file% has %cnt2% lines 
                IF %cnt2% LSS 2     (
                    exit /b
                )   else (
REM Call D:\bin\To_do_something.bat
                )
            )
        )
)
```

But when I try to run it. If will get the error message as below:

```
D:\Jobs>setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

D:\Jobs>REM Check the DataFile1.csv exist or not.
2 was unexpected at this time.

D:\Jobs>                   IF  LSS 2       (

D:\Jobs>
```

After I commented out the rows check part (Just leave the file check part), it works fine.

Any thoughts? Thanks a lot!

Comment: adding the quotes.. `IF "%cnt1%" LSS "2"` and `IF "%cnt2%" LSS "2"` will get rid of the error and also show you very well that you have empty variables before LSS, so that tells you you need `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. funny enough. you do enable it, but never use it.??

Comment: Thank you Gerhard, I added the quotes. It works now. But the count rows part does not work. Variable cnt1 and cnt2 have no value. Could you please help me? Thanks,

Comment: You need to actaully use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` which you have set. As a hint replace the variables starting and ending with % with ! For instance `if !cnt1! LSS 2` for more help do `setlocal/?` from cmdline. Also review your code loop parenthesis

Comment: Thank you so much Gerhard, It works now:)

Comment: Let me know if I should add an answer to reflect the comments given.

Answer (score 0):

Typical Delayed Expansion error. You can read countless posts about it on this forum. Check out my answer here
[Batch file 'for' loops - multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121138/batch-file-for-loops-multiple-lines/19121310#19121310)